# Can't remove touchmove event - Vue watcher

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Function to prevent scrolling on mobile devices:

```
const hideScroll = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
}
```

Adding listener:

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', hideScroll, { passive: false })
```

Removing listener:

```
document.body.removeEventListener('touchmove', hideScroll)
```

In chrome devtools i clearly see, that adding this listener works, i can't scroll using touch, but when i fire `removeEventListener` it's not being removed, i see this in a chrome dev tools and i can't scroll using touch. Using this in a Vue watcher:

```
watch: {
  // hidescroll function is here: const hideScroll = function(e) {}
  chatWindow(newValue) {
    if (newValue) {
      // adding listener
    } else {
      // removing listener
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I just tried it with chrome and the mobile device "emulator", and it works fine. Adding the listener prevents the scroll, removing it makes the scroll working again.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener#Matching_event_listeners_for_removal

Comment: What is `window` in your Vue component, and are you sure the watcher is being called with a falsy value ?

Comment: @Seblor, `chatWindow` is a `data()` property. When i click on a button it toggles to `true` or `false`. I already tried to put `console.log()` in both of states - they're firing successfully.

Comment: can you put more of your Vue code? where do you keep your `hideScroll` function?

Comment: @fila90, updated an answer, `hideScroll` is actually firing. But not removing the listener.

Comment: @AlexanderKim but `watch` is an object, you can't define your function there like that? 

or you define it inside of `watch.chatWindow` watcher ?

Comment: @fila90, it's an object, right. Sure, i can define it as method. Why you think that i can't?

Comment: well, you can't define it like this `const hideScroll = function(e) {}` if it's a method :D. can you copy your whole component to jsfiddle or somewhere else

Comment: Works fine in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/RmVzJe) (tested in Chrome 74 on macOS)

Comment: @fila90, lol, indeed, i moved that const out of `watch: {}` and it works as intended now :D I wrote about this in my answer as a comment: `// hidescroll function is here: const hideScroll = function(e) {}`

Comment: @fila90, make an answer, i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move `hideScroll` function out of your watcher.

right now you're creating new function every time watcher gets triggered. function looks the same, but it's not the same instance that is attached to event listener and that's why you can't remove it.